# ヘルプセンターの「どのような質問は避けるべきですか?」で MetaFilter's FAQ へのリンクがされていない

Tags: バグ, 完了

[英語版SOの「What types of questions should I avoid asking?」](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)では

> (The above section was adapted from [MetaFilter’s FAQ](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter).)

として `MetaFilter's FAQ` にリンクが設定されていますが、[日本語版の「どのような質問は避けるべきですか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)では、

> (上記のセクションは、MetaFilter’s FAQ (MetaFilter の FAQ) から改作したものです。)

となっていて、リンクが設定されていません。